# ORDER BY múltiples Select dentro de UNION

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla de publicaciones y quiero traer las publicaciones de mi ubicacion completa (ciudad, estado y pais), luego las publicaciones de estado y pais (excepto las anteriores) y luego las del país (excepto las anteriores), y que cada una de las consultas esté ordenada por fecha (primero los más nuevos). Tengo un "UNION" de las tres consultas con su ORDER BY interno, pero parece no tomarlo en cuenta.

```
(
    SELECT id, pais, estado, ciudad, created_at 
    FROM publicaciones 
    WHERE pais = 'PA' AND estado = '1' AND ciudad = '1' 
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
)
UNION 
(
    SELECT id, pais, estado, ciudad, created_at 
    FROM publicaciones 
    WHERE pais = 'PA' AND estado = '1' 
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
)
UNION
(
    SELECT id, pais, estado, ciudad, created_at 
    FROM publicaciones
    WHERE pais = 'PA' 
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
)
```

Obtenido:

```
 id pais estado ciudad created_at
 20 PA   1      1      2019-01-19 05:57:20
 25 PA   1      1      2019-01-20 08:57:20
 21 PA   1      2      2019-01-19 06:26:24
 26 PA   1      2      2019-01-20 08:26:24
 22 PA   2      2      2019-01-19 06:32:38
 24 PA   2      2      2019-01-20 08:24:38
```

Esperado:

```
 id pais estado ciudad created_at
 25 PA   1      1      2019-01-20 08:57:20
 20 PA   1      1      2019-01-19 05:57:20
 26 PA   1      2      2019-01-20 08:26:24
 21 PA   1      2      2019-01-19 06:26:24
 24 PA   2      2      2019-01-20 08:24:38
 22 PA   2      2      2019-01-19 06:32:38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma sencilla es usar una subconsulta y definir una columna para manejar el orden:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM (

        SELECT 1 as Orden, id, pais, estado, ciudad, created_at 
            FROM publicaciones 
            WHERE pais = 'PA' AND estado = '1' AND ciudad = '1' 

        UNION 

        SELECT 2 as Orden, id, pais, estado, ciudad, created_at 
            FROM publicaciones 
            WHERE pais = 'PA' AND estado = '1' 

        UNION

            SELECT 3 as Orden, id, pais, estado, ciudad, created_at 
            FROM publicaciones
            WHERE pais = 'PA' 
    )
    ORDER BY Orden, created_at DESC
```

Como puedes ver `Orden` es una columna definida dentro de la subconsulta con un valor para cada grupo de datos que luego nos permitirá ordenar todo como buscas.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Analicé tu respuesta y se acercaba bastante a lo que necesito, pero me repetía algunas filas, así que lo que hice fue esto  
  
SELECT 1  
`WHERE pais = 'VE' AND estado = '16' AND ciudad = '17'`  
  
SELECT 2  
`WHERE pais = 'VE' AND estado = '16' AND ciudad <> '17'`  
  
SELECT 3  
`WHERE pais = 'VE' AND estado <> '16' AND ciudad <> '17'`  
  
De esa forma obtuve el resultado que esperaba porque primero me trae donde coincidan los tres argumentos ordenados por fecha, luego donde coincidan pais y estado, y por ultimo donde coincida solo el país.

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto pueda ayudarte:

Si se quiere usar una cláusula ORDER BY o LIMIT para ordenar o limitar el resultado completo de una UNION, hay que poner entre paréntesis cada sentencia individual y colocar el ORDER BY o LIMIT después de la última. El ejemplo siguiente usa ambas cláusulas:

```
 (SELECT a FROM tbl_name WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
    UNION
    (SELECT a FROM tbl_name WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
    ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;
```